# Question sur l'adverbe

Tags: adverbes

Un livre de grammaire mentionne :

L'adverbe - comme l'adjectif par rapport au nom - apporte une précision sur un adjectif, un verbe, un autre verbe, une préposition, ou toute une proposition.
(...quelques examples donnés...)
**Comme le mot auquel il se réfère n'a ni genre ni nombre propres, l'adverbe est invariable.**

Certes, je sais que l'adverbe est invariable et cette caractéristique le distingue de l'adjectif. Or, je n'arrive pas à comprendre le sens de l'affirmation soulignée (Comme...invariable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Comme* signifie ici *étant donné que*, autrement dit :

> Les adverbes sont invariables car les mots auxquels ils se réfèrent le sont aussi.

Un adjectif, un verbe, une préposition ou une proposition complète n'ont ni genre (masculin ou féminin) ni nombre (singulier ou pluriel).

Comment: Merci. Cependant un adjectif n'a-t-il pas nombre et genre ?

Comment: Un adjectif n'a pas de genre ou de nombre intrinsèque. Il peut seulement prendre celui du nom auquel il se rapporte.